# How to show products based on taxons & user roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I have a spree site where there are multiple different user roles. Some categories of products are only available to certain users (eg. Wholesale customers can access wholesale products). How would I limit this? I tried to do it using

`<% if spree_current_user.has_spree_role?("wholesale") %>`

`<% @products = Spree::Product.find_by_sql('SELECT sp.* FROM spree_products sp LEFT JOIN spree_products_taxons spt ON spt.product_id = sp.id LEFT JOIN spree_taxons st ON spt.taxon_id = st.id WHERE st.name = "Wholesale"') %>`

in the products partial where it shows the products but this overrides the retrieve_products method so it needs to be done somewhere earlier. I tried it in the /lib/spree/core/search/base.rb retrieve_products but this doesn't recognize spree_current_user...

Sorry for being a noob. Any tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you must create extension

[extension guides](http://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/extensions_tutorial.html)

After under your extension create `/controllers/spree/home_controller_decorator.rb`

In this file put:

```
module Spree
  HomeController.class_eval do
    def index
     @retrieve_prodcuts = # type here your @products code
    end
  end
end
```

Similarly you can do this also for `products_controller`or other controllers.